# Searching a column using LIKE with a leading & trailing %

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

Trying to search for a given string within a column and wanted to display even if its anywhere within that column.

```
Declare @searchText nvarchar(30) = 'an'

SELECT TOP 10
    CASE WHEN LEN(LastName) > 5 THEN LEFT(LastName,5) + '..' 
         ELSE LastName  end as DisplayName,
    LastName as FullName
From [dbo].[Employees]
WHERE 
    LastName like '%' + @searchText + '%'
GROUP BY 
    CASE WHEN LEN(LastName) > 5 THEN LEFT(LastName,5) + '..' 
         ELSE LastName  end,
    LastName
```

I do have a non clustered index on LastName column but as expected its not being used because of leading & trailing %. I understand FullText search is the best bet for it. Apart from that is there any other way one can optimize this script?

Comment: Not really. When you are looking for existence of some characters as part of a string there isn't much you can do. Think about the phone book analogy. You are asking to find all names that contain "an". The only way to do this is to look at each and every single row. There is no shortcut.

Comment: [I wrote about one cumbersome but effective approach, and also pointed out a couple of other options](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/02/sql-indexes/seek-leading-wildcard-sql-server).

Comment: You should examine FullText Search catalogs, or an external search provider like Lucene.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments